# How to convert T-SQL date functions to Databricks sparkSQL

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I have the following T-SQL code

```
SELECT eomonth(dateadd(quarter, -1,datefromparts(year(sysdatetime()), (month(sysdatetime()) / 4 + 1) * 3, 1)))
```

And I need to convert it to sparkSQL

I think I can convert the end of the month (eomonth) with the following:

```
last_day(add_months(current_date())
```

But I'm not sure how to convert the full T-SQL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `SELECT last_day(add_months(date_trunc('quarter', current_date()), -1))`

Comment: Are you trying to get the last day of the month for the end of the previous quarter.

Comment: Hi @Aswin, the result should give me the following date 31/03/2023. Thanks

Comment: The above spark SQL query gives the same result

Comment: Great. I haven't tested yet, but thank you.

Comment: I was going ask if you wouldn't mind converting the following  to sparkSQL as well ```SELECT eomonth(dateadd(MONTH, -1, sysdatetime()))```. But if you rather I post it as separate question I will. Otherwise, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253988/discussion-between-aswin-and-patterson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:1**

```
SELECT last_day(add_months(date_trunc('quarter', current_date()), -1))
```

The above code first truncates the current date to the beginning of the current quarter using the `date_trunc` function. It then subtracts one month from the resulting date using the `add_months` function, and finally gets the last day of the resulting month using the `last_day` function.

[image]

**Code:2**

```
select  date_add( date_trunc('quarter', current_date()),-1)
```

The above query subtracts one day from the beginning of the current quarter.

[image]

Any of the above codes will give the result `2023-03-31`.