# Modifying sparkSQL code to return a specific date

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks-sql

I received some great help from a SO member in creating sparkSQL that return the end of the last quarter based on the current date, see below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76423093/how-to-convert-t-sql-date-functions-to-databricks-sparksql/76423642#76423642)

```
SELECT last_day(add_months(date_trunc('quarter', current_date()), -1))
```

I would like help modifying the code such that it can return again the end of the last quarter but this time from previous quarter minus one. For example, based on todays date the end of the last quarter for last year would be 31st December 2022, minus one would 30th September 2022. Therefore, can someone help modify the code such that it returns 30/09/2022?

A SO member spotted an error in my question.
Based on my question, the modified code should return 31/12/2022, not 30/09/2022

Comment: if you want prev qtr - 1, then shouldn't you get 31-Dec-2022 (based on current date)?

Comment: Hi @samkart, thanks for getting in touch. Yes you are correct. Well spotted. I will update question

Comment: if you change the `-1` in your query to `-4` (-1 - 3 because 3 months in a quarter), it should give you what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the `-1` to `-4` will give you previous quarter minus 1.

`-4` because there are 3 months in a quarter and you want to subtract a quarter.

```py
spark.sql('SELECT last_day(add_months(date_trunc("quarter", current_date()), -4)) as qtr').show()

# +----------+
# |       qtr|
# +----------+
# |2022-12-31|
# +----------+
```